# How to determine if Local Player won a Google Play TurnBasedMatch?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am making an Android game using Xamarin.Android and MonoGame. I am using Google Play's [TurnBasedMatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch.html#getParticipant(java.lang.String)) API to handle the multiplayer aspect of the game.

At the end of a match I would like to determine if the *local player* (the player who is logged into Google Play on the device) has won the match. Basically, I want to be able to say "You Win!" or "You Lose!" appropriately.

Suprisingly I haven't been able to find anything in the TurnBasedMatch library to find out if *I* won the match. I am sure I must be missing something obvious. Has anyone figured out a way to determine this information?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this limitation by deduction. My game is only 2 players, so I check the name of my opponent with [getDescriptionParticipant](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch.html#getDescriptionParticipant()) ("Get the participant representing the primary opponent in the match.")  and if that is *not* the name of the winning participant (which my game stores) then I know that the local player has won.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
String localPlayerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId( getApiClient());   
Participant localParticipant = mMatch.getParticipant( mMatch.getParticipantId( localPlayerId));
ParticipantResult result = localParticipant.getResult();

if (result != null && result.getResult() == ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_WIN) {
  // Local player won, show greetings...
}
```

Note: For that to work you must previously have called finishMatch(..) with the participant results like this:

```
List<ParticipantResult> participantResults = new ArrayList<ParticipantResult>();
participantResults.add( new ParticipantResult( participantId1, ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_WIN, 1));
participantResults.add( new ParticipantResult( participantId2, ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_LOSS, 2));

Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(
    getApiClient(),
    mMatch.getMatchId(),
    gameData,
    participantResults
);
```